# try/catch with Qt, MFC and CMake

Tags: c++, qt, mfc, cmake

I use CMake to create my projects. In the project I use mainly Qt C++ and some MFC functions for hardware interface. Does it make any sense to use **try/catch e->ReportError()** or some other exception statements in the code?

Comment: Could you clarify how cmake has anything to do with exception handling?

Comment: I only explained in detail how I create and compile my projects.

Comment: Whether to use or not exceptions is not related to Qt, MFC or even Cmake.

Comment: Mixing Qt and MFC? That's highly unusual.

Comment: @all Do you have some other ideas? I'm still looking for answers.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can of course use exceptions together with Qt. The question is just, how useful they are. As an example, consider the following class

```
class Thrower : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void throwException()
    {
        throw 42;
    }
};
```

The exception is thrown inside a slot. To catch this exception, you have to wrap the
signal, which triggers the slot, in a `try` block, e.g.

```
class Catcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Catcher(Thrower* t)
    {
        connect(this, SIGNAL(test()), t, SLOT(throwException()));
    }

    void catchTest()
    {
        try
        {
            emit test(); // Will trigger Thrower::throwException().
        }
        catch (int number)
        {
            qDebug() << "Caught" << number;
        }
    }

signals:
    void test();
};
```

Unfortunately, it is not always possible to use this approach. For example, when you connect `QPushButton::clicked()` to `Thrower::throwException()`, clicking the button
will cause a crash of the event loop.

You could wrap `QApplication::exec()` in a `try`-block, but when you catch the exception, the GUI is most likely already destructed, so there is no real possibility to recover from an exception.

Also have a look at the [Qt documention](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/exceptionsafety.html) about exception safety.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MFC to create a dialog, you will only want to throw pointers to CException derived objects if you throw anything at all. This is because the `DoModal` function contains a catch to restore critical application state, followed by a re-throw; if you throw any other kind of exception it will be missed and your application will be hung.

I don't know if Qt has a similar problem.

Comment: I'm not using MFC to create any dialogs. I use MFC for hardware communication und Qt for GUI and dialogs

Comment: _This is because the DoModal function contains a catch to restore critical application state, followed by a re-throw;_ 
@Mark Ransom what about CWnd::InvokeHelper function? Does the function contain a catch to restore critical application state?

Comment: @ViktorTarasov, I discovered this by looking at the source for CDialog::DoModal. You can do the same.